# Primary keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key, create-table

I am trying to create a table from an existing table. Will the primary keys from the existing table transfer over to the new table?

create table B as select column1, column2, column3 from A.

In table A, the primary keys are column1 and column2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` does not automatically create any indexes for you. This is done intentionally to make the statement as flexible as possible. If you want to have indexes in the created table, you should specify these before the `SELECT` statement:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE bar (UNIQUE (n)) SELECT n FROM foo;
> ```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html)

Comment: So to clarify, the statement UNIQUE(n) creates the primary key for table bar, where n is the primary key in foo?

Comment: @Q17 Right, but I think you're looking for `CREATE TABLE test (PRIMARY KEY (n)) SELECT 1 AS n`